# Liferay service builder 6.2

Tags: spring, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

It is a basic question. What is the main advantages of using the service builder? If my portlet doesn't have anything to do with database, everything is of using webservices, will service builder help in any case like caching? will the service builder provides service layer, so that i can apply AOP on it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Service without any attrs, so service builder will create all the services and injections for these services.

The advantage maybe could be having a service wrapper, You can also use Liferay Catching solution.
For example you use services classes, and create method that calls Web Services.

Well there you can use the liferay cache solution.You can take a look to this class: MultiVMPoolUtil.java

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually in the service builder "LocalServiceImpl" class, i have added a method for calling webservices. but the same is not getting generated in the "LocalServiceUtil" after rebuilding.  The return type will be a custom data type which is not available in model folder. If i comment the internal implementation of the method and have the data type that is available in the model, then the method is getting generated in "LocalServiceUtil".

My question is whether it is not possible to use the datatypes which is available in package other than model. if yes how can we do ?

Comment: In the solution I've done I have a model-project  which is generated as a jar and placed in liferay lib global path (tomcat/lib/ext). Also I have the service.jar in global path. So in this way you can access from anywhere to these services. Where are your model classes located? And also where is your service.jar located? Is it in Portlet lib or in Portal lib?